# Selecting data between records in Yahoo Query Language

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-api

I have a statement which is:

SELECT * FROM music.video.search WHERE keyword="name of artist"

how do i set where i want to start the page result from to when i want to finish with the page count?

So i want something like:

SELECT * FROM music.video.search WHERE keyword="name of artist" ? start=12&end=20

this should return records between 12 to 20

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a bit funky, so take a look at the YQL documentation under [Paging and Table Limits](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html).

Limits are applied right after the table name, so for example this query will return 20 results, starting with offset 12:

```
SELECT title FROM music.video.search(12,20) WHERE keyword="cash"
```

There are both **remote limits** and **local limits**, so take a read through the YQL docs to understand the difference. That page also links to some good examples.